# How to list .so files that are loaded on python script run?

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, shared-libraries

How to list all .so files (full path) that are loaded on python script run?

Is it possible to get full path of (for example) `libcudart.so.10.1`?
Is it possible to get list of .so (full path) that are loaded?

For example I'm running:

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; tf.test.is_gpu_available()"
```

Output:

```
2019-09-27 15:02:27.186029: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2019-09-27 15:02:27.657901: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0 with properties:
name: TITAN RTX major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.77
pciBusID: 0000:17:00.0
2019-09-27 15:02:27.658580: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 1 with properties:
name: TITAN RTX major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.77
pciBusID: 0000:65:00.0
2019-09-27 15:02:27.658766: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2019-09-27 15:02:27.659868: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2019-09-27 15:02:27.661073: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2019-09-27 15:02:27.661305: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2019-09-27 15:02:27.662477: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2019-09-27 15:02:27.663054: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2019-09-27 15:02:27.665455: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2019-09-27 15:02:27.667986: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1763] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1
2019-09-27 15:02:27.668031: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2019-09-27 15:02:27.669523: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1181] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-09-27 15:02:27.669535: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1187]      0 1
2019-09-27 15:02:27.669542: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1200] 0:   N N
2019-09-27 15:02:27.669546: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1200] 1:   N N
2019-09-27 15:02:27.674204: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1326] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 22845 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: TITAN RTX, pci bus id: 0000:17:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2019-09-27 15:02:27.675838: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1326] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:1 with 22823 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: TITAN RTX, pci bus id: 0000:65:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running under Linux, depending on you environment, you can get the information using one of those alternatives:

1. ld.so debug flags
2. strace

With ld.so debug flags, you can activate debug mode by setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable to 'libs' (or even 'all') before your run the python code (depending on your shell: export LD_DEBUG=libs, or setenv LD_DEBUG libs). Dynamically loaded libraries search path will be displayed to stderr.

Look at ld.so man page for additional options.

Sample output - from LD_DEBUG=libs (using python 'import json')

```
owner@vm1:~/Project/stackoverflow/58152351$ python
     28796: find library=libc.so.6 [0]; searching
     28796:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     28796:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
     28796: 
     28796: find library=libpthread.so.0 [0]; searching
     28796:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     28796:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
     28796: 
     28796: find library=libdl.so.2 [0]; searching
     28796:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     28796:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
...
>>> import json
     28796: 
     28796: calling init: /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_json.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
     28796:
```

As an alternative, strace can be used, but parsing it's output requires significantly more effort. The 'stat' lines may provide information about the search path for each library.

Comment: Does actual load of .so is lines with `calling init` ?

Comment: Also seems I can't grep only cuda related libs like: `LD_DEBUG=libs python -c "import tensorflow as tf; tf.test.is_gpu_available()" | grep cuda`

Comment: Note that output from LD_DEBUG goes to standard error. Easy way to grep is to place stderr into a file (python ... 2>/tmp/myerr.out), then grep the library that you want in /tmp/myerr.out

Comment: Works like: `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='1' LD_DEBUG=libs python -c "import tensorflow as tf; tf.test.is_gpu_available()" 2>&1 | grep cuda`